# INI file reader function is addressing wrong values to my structure, How do I solve this?

Tags: c, file, ini

This is for a project for university (small replica of a Catan game) and I'm struggling a bit with this part, we have the read an INI file with fairly simple formatting, it only has some comments starting with ';' and then it's just tags with a value in front:

```
xdim=4
ydim=5
N=D
S=L2
E=S10
W=D
etc...
```

I have this function to read from an INI file and address the read values to the correct struct element. But it seems like it doesn't even read the file, the struct is a simple struct with xdim and ydim, after I call the func xdim is '&d&d&d&d etc...' and ydim is 0

I've tried placing in some printf's just to see if the values from the INI file itself where being read wrong, but nothing is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 128

typedef struct UNIT { /**struct used in an array for the rest of the INI values*/
    char N[4];
    char S[4];
    char W[4];
    char E[4];
    char Building;
}UNIT;

typedef struct{ /**This is declared in main and passed to the functions*/
    UNIT *grid;
    unsigned int xdim;
    unsigned int ydim;
} MAP_CONFIG;

void set_config_val(MAP_CONFIG *config, const char *key, int val) {

    if (config == NULL)
    return;
    if (strcmp(key, "xdim") == 0){
        printf("here");
        config->xdim = val;
    }
    else if (strcmp(key, "ydim") == 0){
        printf("here");
        config->ydim = val;
    }
    else{
        ;
    }
}

void read_config(MAP_CONFIG *config,FILE *f) {

    char str[MAX];
    char *token;
    const char *delim = "=\n";

    while (1) {
        fgets(str, MAX, f);
        if(feof(f)!= 0) break;
        puts(str);
        if (strchr(str, '=')!=NULL) {
            char varname[MAX];
            int value;

            token = strtok(str, delim);
            strcpy(varname, token);

            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
            value = atoi(token);
            printf("&d", token);
            set_config_val(config, varname, value);
        }
    }



    config = malloc(sizeof(MAP_CONFIG));
    config->grid = calloc(config->xdim * config->ydim, sizeof(UNIT));



    close(f);
    return;
}
```

open file function:

```
FILE *openFile(char *nome, char *mode) {
    FILE *f;
    printf("Opening file %s\n", nome);
    f = fopen(nome, mode);

    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** It was not possible to open the file %s.", nome);
        exit(1);    
    }
    return f;
}
```

test main im using:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    MAP_CONFIG map;
    MAP_CONFIG *mapa = &map;
    FILE *f;
    char *filename;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("Parametro %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    if (argc >= 2) {
        filename = argv[1];
    }
    else {
        printf("Opening base map file..\n");
        filename = "mapa.ini";
    }

    f = openFile(filename, "r");
    read_config(mapa, f);
    printf("%d %d", map.xdim, map.ydim);

    return 0;
}
```

I just want it to read the xdim and ydim, and then repeat the process to an array of structs for each struct to get the correct value of the N,S,E,W present in the INI file... Help!

Comment: `printf("&d", token);` should be `printf("%s", token);`

Comment: and `close(f)` should be `fclose(f)`, though arguably that shouldn't be there *at all*; the *caller* should close that file pointer, seeing as they're the ones that opened it.

Comment: Did you open the file (successfully)? To avoid this type of dialog, please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Please don't correct mistakes which were pointed out *in the post* or these comments won't make any sense. Rolled back.

Comment: @WeatherVane I did open the file successfully, i wrote the code starting from that point, after it opened successfully I continued with this. The mistakes were made by me when I posted my problem here, My file is correct, fclose and "%s" pointed by the other users, my bad

Comment: Please [read the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You might believe you did open the file correctly, but it becomes uphill to find out if you *really* did! Use copy/paste to place your code here, then that also avoids the "sorry it was a copy typo". We are getting nowhere.

Comment: @WeatherVane posted my .c that im using to test this part of the program, nothing else is being used other than that code.

Comment: You've made it really hard to check the code. I had to piece together the sections, add what I suppose are the headers files you don't show, guess the value of `MAX`, correct the two typos and comment out the four debugging outputs. Having compiled it, the program prints `4 5` on one line so it appears to work correctly. However you haven't written the part that stores the string values, it's left blank. That function only takes an `int` data argument anyway. Another thing is you try to allocate memory in `read_config` *after* it is needed, and overwrite the pointer argument passed. . .

Comment: . . . You are welcome as a new contributor but can you please look up what an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is and understand why people ask for one?